# CSS circle without using fixed width and height

Tags: html, css

I want to display the notification count inside a circle but I don't want it to have a fixed width so the circle can expand when there is a bigger number/text inside the circle.

```css
.circle {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">5</div>
<br>
<div class="circle">102</div>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

See this CSS only solution. Set the same value of `min-width` and `min-height` for 1 digit number. Use a pseudo element for vertical alignment and to maintain the square shape. With `border-radius` applies to the container for the circle.

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  min-width: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.circle:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 100%;
  height: 0;
}
.circle span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"><span>8</span></div>
<div class="circle"><span>64</span></div>
<div class="circle"><span>512</span></div>
<div class="circle"><span>4096</span></div>
```

**EDIT**

New approach by using newer CSS features, namely `aspect-ratio`

```css
.circle {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  line-height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  display: inline-grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-width: 2em;
  min-height: 2em;
  padding: .5em;
  background-color: silver;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">8</div>
<div class="circle">64</div>
<div class="circle">512</div>
<div class="circle">4096</div>
<div class="circle">32768</div>
```

Comment: Yeah... yours is nicer. :P

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: There are 2 tiny issues with this though since it's kind a hacky solution. When there is a single digit number, the shape doesn't look like a full circle. And my second concern is since I'm using this for the notification area, the circle becomes too big for anything more than 2 digits number. Obviously because of `padding: 5px` and also because we're trying to maintain the circle shape. it would be nicer if we could optimize this for small sizes.

Comment: @xperator I added `line-height: 1;` that probably can solve the rounding issue. For the size of the box, one possible way would be reducing the `padding` and `font-size` for larger numbers with different classes perhaps.

Answer (score 8):

This is so hacky, but it seems to check out on all the major browsers' latest versions, so I'll post it anyway.  The basic principle is that percent-based padding (even top and bottom padding) are relative to the width of the parent.  Setting it to `100%` with a width and height of `0` would theoretically mean that the height of the element would always be equal to the width.  Combine that with a pseudo element and you don't even need to change the markup.  I used flexbox to correct the centering of the content.  It seems to work on the browsers I tested it on, but this is definitely dependent on recent versions because it uses `flexbox` and `display:table`. I also had to add a `min-width` to ensure it doesn't appear out of shape for too little of content.

```css
.circle {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  min-width: 1.25em;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circle:after {
  content: '';
  padding-top: 100%;
  display:table;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">5</div>
<br>
<div class="circle">102</div>
<br>
<div class="circle">4298347918</div>
```

Comment: If anyone is looking at this three years later after the post like myself, this is the one

Answer (score 4):

Simple CSS for circles that works almost ever:

```
.circle {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

The trick is that the padding top is calculated on the width so you can use it for makinh height equals width

Answer (score -1):

Try using border-radius:50% and set max-width and height

Answer (score -2):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/z6n1uszo/1/) is a quick example where you can see how to dynamically maintain a circle with css and js.

As Jagjit Singh pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41855887/4992594), you can achieve a circle using `border-radius: 50%;` instead of a fixed-pixel value.