# How to create a circle with a number in the center that scales to fit the circle in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, adjustable

There are many solutions for numbers in circles, but they use fixed sized. How to style the circle div for it to contain centered text or number of largest possible font to fit the circle?

Comment: i see... ill try to narrow down the question

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855730/css-circle-without-fixed-width-and-height/41856203#41856203

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - Circle without fixed width and height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855730/css-circle-without-fixed-width-and-height)

Comment: This do trougth JS, calculate width and apply to height value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this code solves your problem. Just make sure the font-size and the width of the parent is same, (5 rem in this example).

```css
div{
  font-size: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;

  background-color: aquamarine;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>5</div>
```